# How to open a webpage in ImGui

Tags: imgui

I've looked everywhere, and I can't seem to find the solution to my problem. I am wanting to know how I could use imgui to open a popup window and opening a chrome window with a website like "https://google.com". I thought that ImGui::OpenPopup might work, but then I looked at the function and then on google and it seemed like it wouldn't work. When you click a button and it redirects to a window on your computer, like when you click a link in discord and it opens a google tab on your computer.

I assumed it may look a little like this

```
void GUI::renderAboutMenu() noexcept
{
    if (ImGui::MenuItem("My Discord"))
        openWebsite("https://discord.gg/myinvitecode");
    if (ImGui::MenuItem("My Patreon"))
        openWebsite("https://patreon.com/myinvitecode");

}
```

Comment: Unlikely that ImGui supports a whole HTML Browser

Comment: I mean that when you click a button and it redirects to a window on your computer, like when you click a link in discord and it opens a google tab on your computer

Answer (score 6):

It's not really a dear imgui question, more about how to use your OS API to perform that.

Something like that would work:

```
void OsOpenInShell(const char* path)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    // Note: executable path must use backslashes!
    ::ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", path, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
#else
#if __APPLE__
    const char* open_executable = "open";
#else
    const char* open_executable = "xdg-open";
#endif
    char command[256];
    snprintf(command, 256, "%s \"%s\"", open_executable, path);
    system(command);
#endif
}
```